# Python program does not show the print() and closes itself

Tags: python, function, debugging

```
services_array = []
passwords_array = []

def main_program():

    user_service = input("Il nome del servizio è: ")
    services_array = [user_service]

    user_password = input("Inserisci la password: ")
    passwords_array = [user_password]


def show_inputs(services_array, passwords_array):
    for services in services_array:
       for passwords in passwords_array:
           print (services + " --------- "+ passwords)

main_program()
show_inputs(services_array, passwords_array)
```

I'm new to python and I'm using Pycharm to write my code. I just started writing this password manager and when i run it I have some problems:
1. It does not print out your inputs
2. It closes right after you insert your inputs
They could sound so stupid to you guys but since I'm not an expert coder, I'm struggling resolving them. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing left to do after taking inputs and printing them, so of course the program closes. Why shouldn't it close?

Comment: is there a way to stop this? I mean I dont want it to close

Comment: Are you asking because you don't want the _terminal_ to close in which the program is running? There's no reason to keep the _program_ itself running, is there?

Comment: It's supposed to be a password manager so after you input the service and the password you should be able to see them so I dont want the terminal t o close instantly

Comment: Well, I guess you can just add `input()` at the end of the code. That'll make it stay open until the user presses Return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use append

```
services_array = []
passwords_array = []

def main_program():

    user_service = input("Il nome del servizio è: ")
    services_array.append(user_service)

    user_password = input("Inserisci la password: ")
    passwords_array .append(user_password)


def show_inputs(services_array, passwords_array):
    for services in services_array:
       for passwords in passwords_array:
           print (services + " --------- "+ passwords)

main_program()
show_inputs(services_array, passwords_array)
```

Comment: Okay, but why? Could you explain why `append` works, but an assignment doesn't?

Comment: I am newly start with python and this problem faced me and find this solution

Comment: I have a point in this code you try to print the arrays using two for loops and it seems to be wrong because this code will get the first services with all the existing passwords

Comment: I dont think so when I run it it does not happen :O

Comment: try to add more than one user_service and passwords and thin u will find this bug

Comment: please vote my answer if it  works

Comment: you are right, didnt notice that